# Proof of this trace inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, trace

In an article I was reading, it is written:
It is well-know that for any two matrices X and Y of appropriate sizes we have
$$|tr\, X^*Y| \leq \frac{tr \, X^*X + tr \, Y^*Y}{2}$$

I didn’t find it obvious and I couldn’t find a proof. 
I’ve tried to it it terms of summation but did work. How can I prove it? Or where can I find a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $(X,Y)\mapsto tr(X^*Y)$ is a positive definite inner product on the set of matrices. Hence, by Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$
|\operatorname{tr}(X^*Y)|\le \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(X^*X)\operatorname{tr}(Y^*Y)}.
$$
Now use the inequality $2\sqrt a\sqrt b\le a+b$, which holds for all $a,b\ge 0$ by the binomial formula.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use $\operatorname{tr}(A+B) = \operatorname{tr}A+\operatorname{tr}B$ and
\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr}((X-Y)^\ast(X-Y))\geq 0.
\end{align}

**Additional Hint**: Also consider
\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr}((X+iY)^\ast(X+iY))\geq 0.
\end{align}

Comment: But why do we have $tr((X-Y)^*(X-Y)) \geq 0$ in first place. And if we have it, this gives us that $Re tr(X^*Y) \leq ....$ and not |tr X^*Y|

Comment: Oh i know why it’s positive, because A^*A is always positive semidefinite. But still thinking about how to get to the inequality